# Computed width in chrome with device mode

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile

Please see the simple snippet. I am using chrome 58.

- While i turned on device mode, iphone 6 (375*667px), computed width
  shows:490px.
- While i turn off device mode, and narrow down the viewport width to
  exactly 375px, the computed width shows 187px.

why is that kind of difference?

```css
div {
  height:100px;
  background-color:green;
  width:50vw;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't specific to Chrome, but rather because screen resolution is **not** equal to browser window size. The CSS unit `vw` stands for **viewport width**, and is relative to the **viewport**. This is your screen minus the reserved space of the browser chrome. Keeping in mind how many different devices and browsers there are, this reserved space can differ greatly. For more information on this, see **[Screen Resolution != Browser-Window](https://css-tricks.com/screen-resolution-notequalto-browser-window/)**.

To work around this, you can set the viewport width in the `<meta>` to be measured off of the **device-width**:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
```

It's also recommended to use [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to target specific **breakpoints**. If you want to get fancy, you can even target [**specific devices**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/). To help with this, **[WebSiteDimensions](http://www.websitedimensions.com/)** has a nice chart illustrating the various different 'safe areas' for different devices.

Hope this helps! :)